# VBA how to declare and set toggle button outside of subs?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find some way to declare and set variable outside of all subs.

I have a toggle button (called EN) in sheet Start. I am using line

`If Sheets("Start").EN.Value = True Then`

many times in many subs and I wonder if there is a way to make it shorter. I still learn VBA and I know I can declare object above subs, but I cannot use Set statement (it shows Invalid outside procedure error). Is it possible to declare and set object outside of subs?

Comment: No, you can declare but not set.

Comment: Thank you (in sad but grateful way)